# popup is not displaying in new versions of browsers

Tags: jquery, session, browser, popup, cross-browser

I am building a popup where popup will display on any page of the website but if 60 seconds is over and we try to refresh the page or change the page then it will not display again.

here is my code, it is working fine on old versions of browsers but not in IE11, Chrome 58 etc.:

```
 if(sessionStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown'){
 //
sessionStorage.setItem('popState','shown')
    }
```

Thakns in advance...

Comment: The popup-blocker is blocking it.

Comment: Popup blockers block any call to `window.open()` that isn't in the code run by a user event handler. If you run it later with `setTimeout`, it's no longer linked to the original event.

Comment: Barmar, i am not using any popup-blocker.

Comment: All modern browsers have a built-in popup blocker. Did you disable it?

Comment: yes i disabled it, still it is not working.

Comment: do you have any alternate sothat if time is over than popup will not display either we refresh or change the page.